# Comparar id que sean true o devolver false

Tags: reactjs

necesito comparar dos id que son checkbox, si son iguales o checked los 2 un button se desactive o active el disabled. no me funciona.

tengo esto:

no se si lo entenderás no me deja pegar mucho código te paso en enlace, en teoría hay 2 checkbox que deben habilitar el botón cuando los 2 estén seleccionados o cuando todos los campos este marcados. no pego todo el código nunca por que es muy extenso.

creo que sera mas difícil así. pero bueno si es lo que pides?

https://jsfiddle.net/joselo01/0me2njbx/2/

Comment: Si compartes el componente completo vamos a tener una mejor idea de lo que estás queriendo lograr.

Comment: ya lo compartí en un enlace, espero lo entiendes, para mi sera mas dificil así. pero bueno?